# Redundant off-topic reasons?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

[image]

Ok? 0.o

> Questions on **identifying a particular song, genre, instrument, etc.** based on a sample or picture are off-topic as they're rarely useful to future readers.

> Questions on **identifying (or finding) a particular song, genre, instrument, etc.** are off-topic since they are rarely useful to future readers.

Isn't that, well, redundant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Us mods can't edit them, so we can only add a new one when we want to tweak them.  Now that the new one has been approved I have removed the old one.